# python function shows--> add_charge not defined when ans is 1st not y or n

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

**it shows error ---> add_charge referenced before assign 
when initial value of ans is not "y" or "n"**

> **function** *choice(ans)* ----> assign add_charge(additional charge) according to input user
>   gave

```
def  choice(ans):
    if ans == "Y" or ans =="y" or ans == "Yes" or ans == "yes":
        add_charge = 100
    elif ans == "N" or ans =="n"or ans =="No"or ans =="no":
        add_charge = 0
    else:
        ans = f_ans() # if ans is other then y or n, ask user again and assign value
        choice(ans)

    return add_charge
```

Comment: But... that's exactly what you wrote. If the first or second condition is met you define it, but it's undefined under `else`. Why would anything else happen?

Comment: i am asking that if and elif condition does not match it will ask again and call choice(ans). now if ans is now y or n if or elif condition meets so does not go to else and return add_charge

Answer (score 2):

You are using recursion where you should use a `while` loop.

When a user picks something other than `yes` or `no` (or variants thereof), you end up in the `else` branch and call `choice()`. That function call *eventually* returns, and at that moment `add_charge` is not set.

You can 'fix' that issue by assigning the return value:

```
else:
    ans = f_ans() # if ans is other then y or n, ask user again and assign value
    add_charge = choice(ans)
```

but you should really use a *loop* here; that way you don't run into namespace issues and won't ever run out of stack either. All it takes is someone holding the ENTER key for you to run into the maximum recursion limit.

You can use `str.lower()` and a set membership test to simplify your tests as well:

```
def choice():
    while True:
        ans = f_ans()
        if ans.lower() in {'y', 'yes'}:
            return 100
        elif ans.lower() in {'n', 'no'}:
            return 0
```

The `return` statements will exit the function, but if neither branch is met (the user gave something other than a valid answer), the `while` loop goes back to the top and `f_ans()` is called again to ask for a valid answer.